# Counter-example Linear Algebra Question - Rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $B$ be an $n \times m$ matrix, and let $A$ be the $(n-1) \times m$ matrix resulting from removing the last row of $B$.

Is it true that $\text{rank}(A)+1 \geq \text{rank} (B) \geq \text{rank} (A)$?

Also, if it is false, can someone please go through your process in coming up with a counter-example?

Comment: The rank of $A$ can't be more than the rank of $B$, and it will at most be 1 less because you remove 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
If you removed a linearly dependent row (so you did not reduce the rank), then $\mathrm{rank}(B) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$, but if you reduced the rank then $\mathrm{rank}(B) = \mathrm{rank}(A) + 1$.

Comment: So is it true  ?

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Why don't you write out a full argument, and I will check it for you. You've been around long enough to know that people here are not into doing your homework for you...

Comment: Case 1: remove a linearly independent row, $\text{rank}A = \text{rank} B - 1$. Case 2: remove a linearly dependent row, $\text{rank} A = \text{rank}B$. So in either case, rank$B$ is rank$A +1$ or rank$A$, which corresponds to the given inequality I think. However, the inequality is a weaker statement, so I don't know... @gt6989b

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove you are right, this is stronger than the inequality, and your argument is correct. Since this is true, and it is stronger, the inequality must also hold.